How to Create a DAX Measure for in Power BI?
When I'm writing a DAX measure using the table name and the column name its not suggesting me the table name in the inteliSense(to auto-complete the table name) and when Im writing the column name its giving me an error "cannot find the column name and the table name"enter image description here

I think you need to create a column, not a measure.
If you want to create a measure, try this
if(MAX('CUSTOMER'[age])

you need to use aggregate function

In DAX, measures are designed to perform calculations based on the filter context of your data model. Because of this, you can't use a column name directly in a measure without wrapping it in an aggregation or other function.
